# Startup.Configuration called but still No owin.Environment item was found in the context

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

We have implemented Asp.net Identity 2.0 on .net 4.5.1, on development machine it is working fine. but on Windows Server 2008 Standard edition with IIS 7 it is giving "No owin.Environment..." exception.

We have moved all Manager and ApplicationUser implementation on another Class Library (Dll) but Startup class is on the same place.

To verify that Startup.Configuration is working, i wrote a file for logging and that worked. but still the same exception.

Then we added Owin Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule in

```
    <remove name="Owin" />
    <add name="Owin" type="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" />
```

but now SessionState is not working.

Comment: Did you finally got it working? I've run into same issue. Startup class is definitely found, so this must be something else. Most annoyingly this happens only on production machine, not on localhost.

Comment: @Darius Well, i upgrade my production server to Windows 2012, so now with upgraded IIS there no issue like that